# layover plots in one figure in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I can layover two curves in 1 plot like so

```
X = np.array([1, 5, 8])
y = np.array([2, 10, 3])

x_max = np.array([5])
y_max = np.array([10])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6));

ax.plot(X, y, 'k--', label="savitzky")
ax.scatter(x_max, y_max, s=200, c='k', marker='*');
```

Then I will get the following:

[image]

Lets say I have a data frame and I want to plot all of its columns at once. I can do that like so:

```
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'col_1':np.array([2, 10, 3]), 'col_2':np.array([3, 4, 7])}, 
                index = np.array([1, 5, 8]))
df_2.plot()
```

to get:

[image]

My question is how can I combine these two so I can plot the whole dataframe at once
and then lay over my vectors of maximum points?(my real data frame is bigger than this, and so are the vectors of maximums)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is one way to do it:

1. Create an axis object `ax`
2. Plot the DataFrame on this axis
3. Get the maximum element and the corresponding index for each column
4. Make a scatter plot on the same axis `ax`

---

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'col_1':np.array([2, 10, 3]), 
                            'col_2':np.array([3, 4, 7])}, 
                            index = np.array([1, 5, 8]))
df_2.plot(ax=ax) # Plot the DataFrame on ax object

max_points = [(df_2[col].idxmax(),  df_2[col].max()) for col in df_2.columns]

ax.plot(*zip(*max_points), 'b*', ms=10) # Unpack the list of (x, y) tuples
ax.set_xlim(None, 8.2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I marked Sheldore's answer as the solution since it was posted earlier.

One thing is that the LOCAL maximums (plotted by *), in each column might be more than 1. i.e. number of (local) max's might be different between columns, one might have 1 max, another column might have 3 max's. So, I have not tested if this solution would work in that scenario. I wrote a for loop before these solutions were posted. But, I hope this question comes handy for others.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

Here I have assigned the axis object given by the `df_2.plot` to `ax` and plotted the further graph on it (`ax`)
    X = np.array([1, 5, 8])
    y = np.array([2, 10, 3])

```
x_max = np.array([5])
y_max = np.array([10])

df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'col_1':np.array([2, 10, 3]), 'col_2':np.array([3, 4, 7])}, index = np.array([1, 5, 8]))
ax=df_2.plot(figsize=(8,6))

ax.plot(X, y, 'k--', label="savitzky")
ax.scatter(x_max, y_max, s=200, c='k', marker='*');

plt.show()
```

[image: <code>Output</code>]